# Tracing a light ray with paths

Tags: python, mesh, scripting, edit-mode

I'm trying to simulate optical rays within blender and am not really advanced within coding for blender or using BGE, so I figured I'd come here for help.

The setup I'm making involves animated surfaces, from which I'd like to reflect a light ray off using a path. Currently I've only managed to do it using the Particles system, however their speed is much too limited in comparison to light speed, to the point the simulation is completely inaccurate.

Ideally I was thinking of a raycaster object that added a vertex to the path whenever it collides with another mesh, gets properly reflected and repeats the cycle until there is no collision left. This would satisfy the need for an "instant" light beam. I, however, have no idea how to do this.

There's this question ([How to trace light rays](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/77398/how-to-trace-light-rays)) but the guy gave a reply which doesn't really answer it.

If you have any idea how to do this, please share it - it may be of use to someone else too.

Thanks.

Comment: You might look into the ray_cast functionality. Specifically https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_71_release/bpy.types.Scene.html#bpy.types.Scene.ray_cast and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/50716/strange-object-ray-cast-behavior

Comment: maybe related: [projecting onto a mirror and back?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/90698/projecting-onto-a-mirror-and-back/91019#91019)